# Python - Calculating Distance in Dijkstra

Tags: python, dijkstra

I am having some trouble in determining the distance of each node from the start node, or rather getting any information back at all. 
I get no output from my function, attached in the following link.

```
#Values to assign to each node
class Node:
     distFromSource = infinity
     previous = invalid_node
     visited = False

#for each node assign default values    
def populateNodeTable(network): 
    nodeTable = []
    index = 0
    f = open('network.txt', 'r')
    for line in f: 
      node = map(int, line.split(',')) 
      nodeTable.append(Node())

      print "The previous node is " ,nodeTable[index].previous 
      print "The distance from source is " ,nodeTable[index].distFromSource 
      index +=1
    nodeTable[startNode].distFromSource = 0 

    return nodeTable

#calculate the distance of each node from the start node
def tentativeDistance(currentNode, nodeTable):
    nearestNeighbour = []
    for currentNode in nearestNeighbour:
      currentDistance == currentNode.distFromSource + [currentNode][nearestNeighbour] #gets current distance from source
      print "The current distance"
      if currentDistance != 0 & currentNode.distFromSource < Node[currentNode].distFromSource:
         nodeTable[currentNode].previous = currentNode
         nodeTable[currentNode].length = currentDistance
         nodeTable[currentNode].visited = True
         nodeTable[currentNode] +=1
         nearestNeighbour.append(currentNode)
         for currentNode in nearestNeighbour:
           print nearestNeighbour

    return nearestNeighbour
```

My logic is, at least in my mind, correct; however, I don't get as much as an error message when the code is run.

Comment: What are you doing to run the code? What are you expecting to happen? What actually happens? This is not the full code; for instance, you haven't defined `infinity`. You'll need to give more details before we can help.

Comment: If that is all your code you are never calling a single function, you define 1 class and 2 functions but I see no calls.

Comment: In essence, I am trying to recreate the Dijkstra's algorithm. The first function, populateNodeTable is assigning all nodes in my file with distance 'infinity', setting all nodes to unvisited, and setting previous node to 'none' - this gives me the output contained in this link: http://pastebin.com/vdk0j892

Comment: Also, just reading through that code, there are a _lot_ of mistakes. You might want to work through a more basic Python tutorial first...

Comment: So, in my second function tentativeDistance, I am attempting to say 'look at the value in my nodeTable from my first function, calculate the distance from the start node and make the appropriate variable assignments as detailed in my tentativeDistance function

Comment: quit asking the same question over and over again, it seems like you asked this 3 times in the last week under different names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `nearestNeighbour` to be an empty list, and then you're looping over it with `for currentNode in nearestNeighbour` -- which does nothing, because the list is empty -- and then you're returning from the function.

(I assume `tentativeDistance` is the function you're calling and seeing nothing from.)

Comment: Ah yes indeed, in that case how could I work out the distance of each node from the source node?

Comment: for currentNode in nodeTable:
      currentDistance = currentNode.distFromSource + currentNode -- this is what I have tried though it says unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'instance'

Comment: @user: that's because `currentNode` is a `Node` and you can't add `Node`s to `int`s. You want to add the weight of the edge; I'm not sure how you're storing that in your data table. Or are the edges unweighted?

Answer (score 1):

You should rethink your algorithm design. Try looking up a pseudocode definition of Dijkstra's algorithm and implementing that in Python. In particular, you should think about the control flow in your program.

You might want to have a look at [this cookbook recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466/) for a Python implementation of Dijkstra and see if you can understand it.

Comment: I have seen that implementation although we have been instructed to read in a file containing the routing information between the nodes which is in the form of numbers separated by commas, e.g. 0,2,4,1,6,0,0, so node c is 4 hops away from node a

Comment: @user: so parse that information into a graph of the form required by your algorithm.

Comment: [[0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5], [0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]]  --  this is my 2d list based on the file contents that I have just created, I'm just not sure how to manipulate this info to work out the distances